# PhpMyAdmin installation throws an 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket' w/ MySQL 5.5

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

each time I try to install phpmyadmin, I get an error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket      
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Each time phpmyadmin tries to "configure" `dbconfig-common`, I have to input mysql-admin PWD and I do it, but it always fails and asks me if I'd like to Perty or Ignore.

I CAN access mysql (`mysql -u root -p`) works well. 
By doing `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` I get following output:

```
root@HP-Pavilion-dv7:/home/<username># /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Shutting down MySQL
.. * 
Starting MySQL
.. *
```

and the same by doing `sudo service mysql start`

P.S. I decided to use mysql 5.5 so I first installed MySQL 5.5 ([quide](http://www.smilecouple.org/2011/07/25/how-to-install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu)) and **then** apache2, php and so on (`sudo aptitude install apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork php5 php5-cli php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-gd phpmyadmin`)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you configured phpMyAdmin for the proper usename and password?

Comment: have you tried this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it/69450#69450

Answer (score 1):

That guide suggests that you use 'alien' to get mysql installed. But the RPM binaries use a different socket path than the mysql client libraries which phpmyadmin ends up depending on.

Unless you have a specific reason to update to mysql-5.5, you're better off using the `mysql-server` package from the Ubuntu archives and connecting to that. 5.5.20 is in Ubuntu precise, so when you upgrade to 12.04, you should get 5.5 then.