# My MySQL installation is broken. How to completely reconfigure it?

Tags: mysql

Here are the following commands I have done.

```
$ sudo service mysql start
mysql start/running

$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

$ aptitude search mysql |grep ^i
i   libapache2-mod-auth-mysql       - Module Apache 2 pour l'authentification vi
i   libdbd-mysql-perl               - Perl5 database interface to the MySQL data
i   libmysqlclient16                - MySQL database client library             
i   mysql-client-5.1                - MySQL database client binaries            
i   mysql-client-core-5.1           - MySQL database core client binaries       
i   mysql-common                    - MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mys
i   mysql-server-5.1                - MySQL database server binaries and system 
i   mysql-server-core-5.1           - MySQL database server binaries            
i   php5-mysql                      - MySQL module for php5
```

Comment: alm - find your mysql.log `cat /var/log/mysql.log` and edit your answer withthis file....

Comment: I like the way you used grep ^i there. Pretty intelligent.

Comment: What exactly does it do? aptitude is installation tools.

Comment: @JimThio That's to find the installed packages related to this question.

Answer (score 18):

Before reinstalling check /var/log/mysql for logs files which may contain clues as to why mysql is not working. If there are no logs log to file might not be enabled in your configuration: [Configure Mysql Error Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html)

To reinstall any package check installed version with

```
dpkg -l|grep mysql-server
```

then for version 5.7 use

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 --reinstall
```

If this doesn't allow you to reconfigure the package you can use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1     did the trick for me when I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 i mysqld wouldn't start and i was forced to manually sudo mysqld

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server --reinstall` this seems a very useful command.

Answer (score 8):

**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can not connect to local MySQL server-through socket '/ tmp / mysql.sock' (2)**

In MySQL installations can specify where we will have the socket for local connections. When making updates is not uncommon to see the error "Can not connect to local MySQL server socket-through." Let's see how to solve this problem.

The error look like this:

```
Mysql-u root-p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can not connect to local MySQL server-through socket '/ tmp / mysql.sock' (2)
```

thru `ps` we can see if is specified by parameter and the place where is it:

```
# ps -fea | grep mysqld
mysql    17661 14003  1 Feb19 ?        00:24:59 /usr/local/mysql-percona/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql-percona --datadir=/var/data/mysql/datadir/data --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
root     23790  7840  0 09:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysqld
```

In this case we see is in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. If not found as a parameter should look into mysqld section of `/etc/my.cnf` to find the parameter:

```
grep socket /etc/my.cnf
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If we know where is it we need to modify the same file (`/etc/my.cnf`) and add the parameter section socket client:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: That is what I was going to put as an answer. I already know this is the correct answer for almost all related problems like this. Will +1 you when I get the ability again.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation! in my case even if i specified a socket in my.cnf it didn't listen on it (params shown in 'ps' are empty and no connection possible. workaround: add 'protocoll=tcp' to client section in my.cnf to force using tcp and not the socket.

Answer (score 2):

*For the latter viewers:*
    I came to the similar error when I failed to upgrade mysql-server package， but I found [this solved my problem](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-mysql-server-depends-on-mysql-server-5-5-however-package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet/). 
When `sudo apt-get install -f` doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`. Now you can reinstall mysql-server.

Comment: please note that  `sudo apt-get purge mysql` wont preserve your databases

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems I am running into is knowing which version I am having issues with.
This was a neat idea:

```
$ aptitude search mysql |grep ^i
```

But here's what I found was critical in the issue:

```
$ apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server-5.x
```

(where x is the version.  If you don't add this, you could be working with the wrong dpkg.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**

```
sudo apt purge mysql*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Description**

1) The first command removes everything related to MySQL with their configuration files.

2) The second one removes those packages which are not needed anymore.

---

Refrences[!]:

1) [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-installation-error-dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-5-5-configure)