# how can i log in to MySQL

Tags: login, mysql

I am new to ubuntu and installed MySQL use a **rpm** file,
and started it use `sudo start mysql`,  when i try

```
mysqladmin -u root password test
```

I get

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I checked the **mysqld** folder and there is nothing
what can i do the next?  Thanks for your answers

Comment: try this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it/69450#69450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you manage to install it using an rpm file??? I'm sure that you're either mistaken or definitely doing something wrong. All you needed to do is

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

UPDATE: There seems to be MySQL 5.5 .deb file [here](http://www.dotdeb.org/2011/11/01/mysql-5-5-is-finally-here/) (although the repository is for Debian) - at any rate, I think it may work better than an rpm

Comment: yeah,I've installed use the **sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client** before, but the MySQL version is 5.1 but I want to install 5.5,so I used alien to convert the rpm file to deb file,then i use **sudo dpkg -i mysql-server.deb** to install it,and now I google a lot but I just didn't find an answer to solve my problem

Comment: If you were following something similar to these instructions - http://www.smilecouple.org/2011/07/25/how-to-install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu - note the use of `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` at the end

Answer (score 7):

first do

```
 sudo mysql_install_db

 sudo mysql_secure_installation

 mysql -u root -p
```

then enter your password

Comment: when i try **sudo mysql_install_db** it says  **Installing MySQL system tables...
/usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu doesnot use `rpm` it uses `deb`. Make sure you have installed mysql i.e.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

It will prompt for password for root user i.e. password for your mysql root user not your system root user.

After that do

`mysql -u root -p`

you will be prompted for password and enter your mysql root password one you entered during mysql installation and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There's some information in the [MySQL Documentation regarding connection errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html). AFAIK you will have to enable access even on localhost by modifying the `bind-address` config parameter: You will have to set it explicitly to 127.0.0.1 to make MySQL waiting for localhost connections. There config file should be `/etc/mysql/my.conf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

Read up on 'auth_socket'.  I moved from another Linux to Ubuntu and burned a day and a half on this.

[can't login as mysql user root from normal user account in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

I need to run `sudo mysqladmin -u root password test` to connect after doing the same steps you did, on ubuntu 18.04.

All the files under `/var/lib/mysql` are owned by `mysql:mysql`, except `debian-5.7.flag` which is owned by `root`.

I don't like this though. Could someone point out if this is harmless or how to fix it?