# can't login as mysql user root from normal user account in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: permissions, mysql

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with the packages `php`, `mariadb` and `nginx`. I ran `mysql_secure_installation` and changed the root password.

Now when I try to login to `mysql` using the root account while logged in Ubuntu as normal user account I get access denied.

When I login using `sudo mysql`, mysql doesn't even ask me password. If I run `mysql_secure_installtion` I see that old settings never got set permanently.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you'd like to get back to the default password less root access via the unix_socket plugin:
```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='unix_socket' WHERE user='root';
flush privileges```

Comment: ^ No, you'd use `alter user root@localhost identified by unix_socket`. The days of manipulating mysq.user tables are long gone. Use the SQL provided.

Answer (score 499):

I recently upgrade my Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 and this has worked for me:

1. First, connect in sudo mysql

   ```
    sudo mysql -u root
   ```
2. Check your accounts present in your db

   ```
    SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
    +------------------+-----------+
    | User             | Host      |
    +------------------+-----------+
    | admin            | localhost |
    | debian-sys-maint | localhost |
    | magento_user     | localhost |
    | mysql.sys        | localhost |
    | root             | localhost |
   ```
3. Delete current root@localhost account

   ```
    mysql> DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
   ```
4. Recreate your user

   ```
    mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
   ```
5. Give permissions to your user (don't forget to flush privileges)

   ```
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)
   ```
6. Exit MySQL and try to reconnect without sudo from your local machine.

<sub>**Edit:** a previous version of the answer post recommended creating a user `'root'@'%'`. However, it is more secure to create `'root'@'localhost'` so connections can only be made from localhost, and not remotely. Both solutions work equally as well for local development.</sub>

I hope this will help someone :)

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, does somebody knows exactly what happened with the root user when you install mysql-server on 16.04?

Comment: Hold it, Doesn't `%` mean you can connect from anywhere...remotely?

Comment: From any host yes, it's not recommended for live environment

Comment: This is a fine solution for local development, if you don't care about remote access security.

Comment: You can change row to:  CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';

Comment: While doing point 4, I am getting __"ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements"__

Comment: To the security-concerned: the unsecured root@localhost mysql connection pattern is a bread-and-butter staple of local development ***but*** should appear absolutely nowhere else.

Comment: @Ruggi I guess it's `myslq_update` that does the magic. for me this was run when normaly upgrading packages on xubuntu 16.10 (also upgrading mysql). so you better set your root pw, 'caus it can happen anytime. and will, probably!

Comment: Solved a big problem, thanks! But I would never figure it out, it doesn't make any sense. None of the commands have affected any rows..

Comment: The grant statement for the new root user here does not give "with grant" to root so root can't grant without running this afterwards: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62046/115679  Please change the grant statement to `grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' with grant option;`

Comment: What exactly is happening here? It appears to just recreate the root user the same as it used to be. What is the difference between this new root user and the original root user?

Comment: @JakeWilson The difference is as explained below:
https://askubuntu.com/a/964762/110005
The reason this solution is working is because the root is being created from scratch but its implementation will cause future problems with grants as noted in these comments. It's much easier to simply update the root user you have than creating a new one.

Comment: Worked! On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks. It helped.
Before I chosen 'disallow remove connection' while mysql_secure_installation. It seems, it was a reason.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: if you are running into *"ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements"* issue follow the steps described here to lower the policy requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094726/your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements

Comment: Sorry, downvoting due to the fact that it is a more overkill approach than less popular answers, and doesn’t even address why the problem is happening. Also due to the ‘root@anywhere’ user it creates.

Comment: Doesn't `IDENTIFIED BY ''` mean anyone will be able to login as root without being prompted for password? Goes nicely with `'root'@'%'` allowing anyone to login to your server from anywhere =-D. I wonder if this answer was posted by hackers who erase data in your DB and demand ransom...

Comment: I have to reset this every few updates... it seems funny. I do use a password tho, I wonder if that is why? After an update I can only "sudo mysql -u root -p" until I do this.

Comment: I really love you, you ended my headache

Comment: Just had this problem with MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 20. This was the only solution that worked!

Answer (score 181):

> If you install 5.7 and don’t provide a password to the `root` user, it
>   will use the `auth_socket` plugin. That plugin doesn’t care and
>   doesn’t need a password. It just checks if the user is connecting
>   using a UNIX socket and then compares the username.

Taken from [Change User Password in MySQL 5.7 With "plugin: auth_socket"](https://dzone.com/articles/change-user-password-in-mysql-57-with-plugin-auth)

So in order to to change the `plugin` back to `mysql_native_password`:

1. Login with sudo:

   ```
   sudo mysql -u root
   ```
2. Change the `plugin` and set a password with a single command:

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
   ```

Of course you can also use the command above to set an empty password.

Just for the record, (and `MariaDB < 10.2` users) there is also another way to only change the `plugin` without providing a password (leaving it empty):

```
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
// to change the password too (credits goes to Pothi Kalimuthu)
// UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', Password = PASSWORD('secret') WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this got set automatically suddenly after an apt-get upgrade I think...

Comment: This finally was the problem after an Update form Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 an i was locked out of my database...

Comment: I guess it's `myslq_update` that does the magic. for me this was run when normally upgrading packages on xubuntu 16.10. so you better set your root pw, 'caus it can happen anytime.

Comment: Also, I like this answer more - it's a lot less destructive ;-)

Comment: Note: You have to use the query for MariaDB < 10.2 as that is the version where `alter user` was added, but it still supports (and uses) the `auth_socket` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the plugin: That makes the difference!

Comment: For MariaDB < 10.2, to change plugin along with the password, here's the query: `UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', Password = PASSWORD('secret') WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537019/1004587

Comment: 10x @PothiKalimuthu, just updated the answer.

Comment: In Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya - I get:  MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'' at line 1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I wish I could vote this up twice.

Comment: I keep coming here after each mysql update, copy pasting the required line, but still not being able to recite it.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'` for this

Comment: You are a good man.

Comment: I wish I could vote this up after every mysql update on ubuntu!

Answer (score 31):

In short, on MariaDB

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', 
      Password = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE User = 'root';
```

where you replace NEWPASSWORD with the password you want, and everything else verbatim.

The issue here is that when MariaDB or MySQL are installed/updated (especially if at some point root is set without a password) then in the Users table the password is actually empty (or ignored), and logging in depends on the system user corresponding to a MySQL user. 
You can test this as follows by switching to system root, and then type:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Then enter either no password or the *wrong* password. You'll probably be let in. (You may even be able to log in from the unix root by simply `# mysql` as the password is irrelevant and the user is defined).

So what's happening? Well, if you log in as root and do the following:

```
select User,host,plugin from mysql.user; 
+----------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User           | host      | plugin                |
+----------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root           | localhost | auth_socket           |
+----------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

you'll note `auth_socket` (which may read `unix_socket` on MariaDB). These sockets ignore passwords and allow the corresponding Unix user in *without* a password check. This is why you can log in with **root** but not with a different user.

So the solution is to update the Users to not use the `auth_socket/unix_socket` and properly set a password.

On MariaDB (<10.2, see comments below) which is on the Ubuntu version 16 as of 2017 this should suffice. NEWPASSWORD is your password. `mysql_native_password` you type verbatim.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', Password = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE User = 'root';
```

(It's possible that setting the plugin to empty would work. YMMV. I didn't try this. So this is an alternative.)

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '', Password = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE User = 'root';
```

Otherwise:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'NEWPASSWORD';
```

Then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For the record, the solution involving deleting the user and recreating it with '%' got me totally locked out of the database, and can cause other problems unless you get the `grant` statement exactly right - easier to simply update the root you already have.

In my experience, the issue only happens with the root user, as other users will be added manually not part of an initial install/update.

Comment: Found this to work perfectly. Makes me wonder though why changing the root password with `mysql_secure_installation` didn't have the same effect. Where does it store the new password?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and say more about each of the commands as you go? I'm not clear on which are applicable. Is it the two `UPDATE`s that apply to MariaDB <10.2 and the `ALTER` to other versions? And is the second `UPDATE` an alternative to the first, or do we need to type both? Finally, is 'mysql_native_password' something to type verbatim, or should we replace it with our intended root password for MySQL?

Comment: @MichaelScheper It's a while back so I don't want to edit too much, but here's what I remember. (1) Do the first UPDATE only (<10.2 may not be a requirement). (2) Yes, type 'mysql_native_password' verbatim. Essentially, what you are doing is telling mariadb: "Don't use Unix priveleges, use the database priveleges". The `mysql_native_password` is that option.

Comment: Damn I spelt 'privilege' wrong!

Comment: Looks like you only missed the edit time limit by 1½ minutes, too! I get frustrated by that sometimes, too. Anyhow, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

By default, `root` user is set to authenticate through an `auth_socket` rather than with a password.

In order to use the password authentication, do:

1. Login to MySQL root shell:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Check authentication methods enabled for different users (optional)

   ```
   SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
   ```
3. Make `root` to authenticate with a password:

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password_here';
   ```
4. Flush privileges for the changes to take effect;

   ```
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
5. Exit and authenticate with your password

   ```
    exit
    mysql -u root -p
   ```

Comment: When I did this, I couldn't sudo mysql as root anymore. I had to su first, and then could log into mysql as root. So I changed it back to auth_socket.

Comment: Single command: `mysql -u root -p -e "use mysql;update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';flush privileges;"`

Comment: If you want to lose access to your MySQL instance, then this answer is the easy way.

Comment: Yes. This worsened the problem.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked on me for a pristine Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install.

Answer (score 3):

Try to create new mysql account, for me it has worked (mysql 5.7.12):

1. Login as sudo:

   ```
   sudo mysql -uroot
   ```
2. Create new user and grant him privileges (no password):

   ```
   CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
   ```
3. Login as new user:

   ```
   mysql -uadmin
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you just run mysql command under root user you will be granted access without asked for password, because socket authentication enabled for root@localhost.
.

The only way to set password is to switch to native authentication like:

> $ sudo mysql
>
> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
> mysql_native_password BY 'test';

Comment: This is actually the only answer that explains what is really happening. Everyone else is shooting from the hip.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code first,

```
echo "CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';" > your_init_file.sql
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;" >> your_init_file.sql 
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> your_init_file.sql
```

and then,

```
killall mysqld
mysqld_safe --init-file=$PWD/your_init_file.sql
```

then  press `Ctrl+Z` and type: `bg` to run the process from the foreground into the background, then verify your access by:

```
mysql -u root -proot
mysql> show grants;
```

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been adapting some provisioning scripts I have created to use MariaDB and ran into this exact issue. Piecing together lots of info here an [Gazzer’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/964762/51813) really zeros in in the issue; it all boils down to the `auth_socket`/`unix_socket` setting.

So when using MariaDB 5.5 (under Ubuntu 14.04) and MariaDB 10 under (Ubuntu 16.04), logging into MySQL and running this command cleared things up right away:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin='' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The other answers—including [the highest voted answer as of this post by Loremhipsum](https://askubuntu.com/a/784347/51813)—really encourage bad practices by recommending dropping a user and then recreating them. To me, that is a pretty radical solution. The best/simplest solution os to nullify the `plugin` value, flush privileges and get on with life.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do two things (thanks to @[Todor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04/991943#801950) and @[Loremhipsum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04/991943#784347)):

```
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost';
```

and then:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I would not recommend to drop user `root`.

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum security**

As unix authentication is the most secure authentication, the best thing to do is leave the default root account as is (i.e. continue to use unix socket authentication with no password) and if not using the root account, use it via `sudo`. If an attacker has root/sudo access; then they already have full control of your server...

When you need to access MySQL/MariaDB via an alternate method (i.e. not CLI), create a new MySQL/MariaDB user with a password and only the required permissions.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and running the following fixed it:

```
mysql_upgrade --force
```

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. I am reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: I just did fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 and installed mariad-server.  
After installing I ran mysql_secure_installation and set password. After going through rest of the steps in mysql_secure_installation, I ran it again and it looks like it is not saving the changes.   

I still can't login from my normal user account.   
Could it be a bug?

Comment: This will never help. The issue has nothing do with the actual install of the MariaDB binary but rather the user `root` being set with `plugin` settings that are non-standard. The only edge case where an upgrade of the DB might help in a case like this is if the `mysql_upgrade` process itself accounts for the `plugin` setting which I doubt.