# MySQL - access denied for user root@localhost

Tags: server, permissions, mysql

I was trying to give remote access to MySQL, as MySQL was only working locally.

I followed this guide
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

I used command like this from tutorial:

```
mysql> update user set Host='202.54.10.20' where user='root';
```

I think this messed up the local mysql.

Now I cannot login with:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

i get this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: Yes)

Now I know the password is right, as it used to work before. but I accidentally locked myself out..

I don't know what to do anymore.

The os used by the server is Ubuntu.

Comment: Can't you just login from the `202.54.10.20`?

Comment: @techraf Yes i could login from remotely, but the websites that were present locally on the server stopped working as cant access the mysql from local.. 

Its very strage, as i can access the mysql remotely but the local user cant access it.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Take a look at this page, it has some possible causes and workarounds to fix this issue, it may help: http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/04/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-user-host-using-password-YES.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try the regular recovery procedure:

1. Stop MySQL service
2. Run the service using:

   ```
   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
   ```
3. Connect (password won't be required):

   ```
   mysql -uroot
   ```
4. Revert your changes (be careful this time and check with `select` what is the current state, host should be `202.54.10.20`):

   ```
   use mysql;
   update user set Host='localhost' where user='root';
   flush privileges;
   ```
5. Restart MySQL the regular way

Comment: Thankyou for reply back, i have tried this, but after the skip-grant command, i am getting this error when i try mysql -uroot

`can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`

Comment: Google for the new problem. There are dozens of reports and different causes.

Comment: ok. somehow i got there, but it says duplicate entry 'localhost-root' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @SizzlingCode I would have to create a new environment and recreate your steps to debug further. I won't be able to do for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

This may also happen if you have no proper privileges. so you can even type the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO '[user]'@'[hostname]' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (updated incorrectly the user host from virtualmin) and fixed it with steps similarly to the answer from @techraf but following similar steps of this site to avoid the `can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` error in ubuntu 16.04:

https://coderwall.com/p/j9btlg/reset-the-mysql-5-7-root-password-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

I modified the steps to update the host instead of the password:

```
# Stop MySQL
sudo service mysql stop
# Make MySQL service directory.
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
# Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.
sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
# Start MySQL manually, without permission checks or networking.
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
# Log in without a password.
mysql -uroot mysql
```

then in mysql:

```
select user, host from mysql.user; --just to check
UPDATE mysql.user SET host='localhost' WHERE User='root' AND Host='202.54.10.20'; --CHANGE the host to the one you see in the query
select user, host from mysql.user; --check again 
commit;
exit;
```

And then in the console:

```
# Turn off MySQL.
sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
# Start the MySQL service normally.
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in Workbench then follow this steps.

First simply log in with your current password:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Then change your password because having low strength password gives error sometimes.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-strong-password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then simply exit and again login with your new password:

```
quit

sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Once you successfully logged in type the command:

```
use mysql;
```

It should show a message like 'Database changed' then type:

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

After that type:

```
UPDATE mysql.user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new-strong-password') where user='root';
```

Then type:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then simply exit:

```
quit
```

Now try to log in with your new password in your WORKBENCH. Hope it will work. Thank you.