# mysql -u root doesnt work but sudo mysql -u root does, why?

Tags: mysql, 17.10

I recently followed some tutorials and installed mysql using 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7

I can connect to the database using password by running the following command:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

I try to connect by running:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: dear downvoter , can you also drop a reason for downvote , atleast an explation why this is an stupid question ?

Comment: This might be related.  Look at some of the answers:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Did you set a root password for mysql during the installation?

Comment: @steeldriver :  yes I did

Answer (score 28):

1. Access with sudo: `sudo mysql -u root -p`
2. Delete the root user: `drop user 'root'@'localhost';`
3. Create the root user again: `create user 'root'@'%' identified by 'your_password';`
4. Give permissions: `grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' with grant option;`
5. Update permission tables: `flush privileges;`
6. Exit MYSQL and try to reconnect without sudo.

Font: [can't login as mysql user root from normal user account in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks! These steps worked for me too and I don't need `sudo` now to use mysql! Looks like replacing the host `localhost` with `%` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: but still cannot access remotely

Comment: Didn't work for me, now I can't get in with or without sudo!

Answer (score 0):

1. Access with **sudo** : `sudo mysql -u root -p`
2. Remove the **super user** : `drop user root@localhost;`
3. **Create a user** the same name : `create user 'root'@'localhost' identified by  'password';`
4. Grant all privileges to the user : `grant all privileges on *.* to  'root'@'localhost';`
5. **Refresh** permission table : `flush privileges;`
6. Exit the table : `exit`
   Now try to access it directly without sudo command.
   works on **Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)**

Comment: The OP is on 17.10 - so it's uncertain if your answer works.

Comment: Just not 100% sure for 17.10.