# How to set/reset mysql password after Installation?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, password

I am runnig Ubuntu 16.04 and followed [this](https://coderwall.com/p/j9btlg/reset-the-mysql-5-7-root-password-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) guide to set/reset root's password. But after all if I am using `$ mysql -u root -p`, or `sudo mysql -u root` on my commandline and enter the new password, I got this error message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I am using *user* und *password* from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` there are no problems to log in with `mysql -udebian-sys-maint -p`.

And if I do so inside of mysql and query for some topic's

```
mysql> select User, authentication_string, password_expired, password_last_changed, password_lifetime, account_locked  from mysql.user; 
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| User             | authentication_string                     | password_expired | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| root             | *obfuscated_authentication_string======== | N                | 2018-11-21 17:02:55   |              NULL | N              |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | N                | 2018-11-21 17:02:48   |              NULL | Y              |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | N                | 2018-11-21 17:02:48   |              NULL | Y              |
| debian-sys-maint | *obfuscated_authentication_string======== | N                | 2018-11-21 17:02:55   |              NULL | N              |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

I see that root's password never has been changed since installation time.

If I follow [these](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/748/how-to-reset-mysql-5-7-root-password-in-ubuntu-16-04) instructions I receive a pid of the background job after step 3 and the shell is prompting

```
$ 2019-07-11T14:21:55.218651Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2019-07-11T14:21:55.226406Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 152: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
2019-07-11T14:21:55.232708Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 152: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

while I have tried to execute `mysql -u root mysql`.

What need I to do for purging, setting or resetting root's password?

Or is it possible to achieve this from within user *debian-sys-maint*?

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Did you try logging back in with a blank password? It's possible the command to set the password wasn't executed properly. By any chance is this a remote system you are trying to log into or is this running locally?

Comment: @Gordster Indeed `mysql` is running locally. `ps -e | grep sql` is displaying a _pid_ for _mysqld_ and if I try to log in without password from terminal with `mysql`, or `mysql -uroot`, or `mysql -u root` the answer is `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'userx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` or `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` like if I would follow the mentioned _guide_ and restart sql.

Comment: Did you try `sudo mysql -u root`? Additionally, I think this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: 1. stop the mysql sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
3. mysql -uroot
5. use mysql;
6. update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
7. flush privileges;
8. quit
9. start mysql sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: @CluelessNoob Yes, I did, but it's resulting in the same error message `ERROR 1045 (28000)`.

Comment: @yusufhari After your 3rd step I got this messages: `2019-07-11T13:35:59.745560Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found following solution with *user* and *password* from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` without start-/stopping any `service` nor `sudo`:

Log in from standard shell:

```
$ mysql -udebian-sys-maint -p
Enter password:
```

Then inside `mysql`:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password("xXnew_pwXx");
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit;
```

Now, without restarting any service I am able to log in with just

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

and the new password **xXnew_pwXx**.

Now it's clearly to see root's password has been changed.

```
mysql> select User, password_last_changed, password_lifetime, account_locked  from mysql.user; 
+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| User             | password_last_changed | password_lifetime | account_locked |
+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| root             | 2019-07-11 16:49:52   |              NULL | N              |
| mysql.session    | 2018-11-21 17:02:48   |              NULL | Y              |
| mysql.sys        | 2018-11-21 17:02:48   |              NULL | Y              |
| debian-sys-maint | 2018-11-21 17:02:55   |              NULL | N              |
+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

That's it ;)