# cannot access mysql 5.7 server as root

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mysql, password, root

I recently installed mysql 5.7 on my ubuntu 18.04 machine, but cannot login as root, I keep getting the infamous 'access denied for 'root'@'localhost' error when trying to connect from the command line.

I have done a lot of research on this problem but most articles someow require that you get into the mysql prompt first by running the sudo mysql -u root command, but the issues is that I cannot even get there.

I have also looked at all my log files , I only have error.log files and no mysql.log files where apparently the temporary root password should be printed out to.

Can someone please tell me how I can reset this root password or if I am missing any steps?

Thank you in advance.
-N

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't login as mysql user root from normal user account in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @Mahdi, well the first step in that article says to run this command sudo mysql -u root, but  when i run this i get the root access error, so I am not sure how to get passed this.

Comment: I finally found the solution in thispost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost