# mysql problem '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql

I got this error on my php script with db:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

and on phpmyadmin:

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

What is the problem, how can i fix this?
I have installed lamp-server..

Comment: If the answer below does not fix it, it would be advisable to show your php code.

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it/69450#69450

Comment: When i use myql -u root -p i get message that it cant connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the mysql server is not running.

In a normal mysql installation, you can check if the server is running with the following command: `service mysql status`

For starting it, just run `service mysql start`.

Comment: It is running, i checked. Any other solution ?
Can i reinstall only mysql, but i have installed lamp server, so it work make any difference to other modules ?
And please give me commands to reinstall mysql

Comment: Could you check what happens after restarting the server? (`service mysql restart`)

Comment: I checked that, but i fixed this with uninstaling mysql-server and mysql-common, then i installed mysql-server and phpmyadmin, and it works, now..

Thanks.

Comment: Kubuntu 13.04 `mysql: unrecognized service`

Comment: Ok, just for information, I had to use sudo mysql start in order to make it work. This answer seems to solve the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I didn't even have the file, so any `mysql` command wouldn't work. I had to run `mysqld_safe` to create a new `mysqld.sock` file. That is:

```
$ cd /etc/init.d/
$ mysqld_safe
```

You'll probably won't get prompt back, but if you restart your session, a mysqld.sock file will be somewhere. Find it with

```
$ sudo find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu 14.04 this is running but the socket is not nor the file present. Replace your database connection host to = 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a local Debian 8 server had shut down while I was away on holiday and by the time I got it restarted it had picked up another IP address from the DHCP server.

I needed to obtain the new IP address like this:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Then I needed to edit my my.cnf file:

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Find this section:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 192.168.0.42
```

and change it to match the correct IP address:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 192.168.0.53
```

After that I had no problem getting the server restarted.

Comment: Mysql defaults to a socket connection when the hostname is localhost, and thus is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

i had mysql :
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

i have done :
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-10.0

results :
no loss of databases and problem resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' is created on SQL service startup and deleted on stop.

Its a temp file.

Its missing because SQL has an issue starting.

Most common reason: Your drive is full.