# mysql service do not launch

Tags: mysql

Sorry for my English;

I was trying to create db with rake in RoR application that has been configured for MySQL(gem installed, settings changed).
After that attempt mysql-server broke:
`d@calister:~$ mysql`
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

mysqld is not running at all:
`d@calister:~$ ps aux | grep mysql` 
`d       3769  0.0  0.0   4368   832 pts/0    S+   18:03   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql`

And also it doesn't seem it would like to run:
`d@calister:~$ sudo service mysql start`
`start: Job failed to start`

Any suggestions?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
d@calister:~$ sudo -u mysql mysqld
120520 18:45:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120520 18:45:11 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120520 18:45:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120520 18:45:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120520 18:45:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
120520 18:45:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120520 18:45:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120520 18:45:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120520 18:45:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120520 18:45:13 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1589459
120520 18:45:13 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it/69450#69450

Comment: first, just try `sudo service mysql start` or `sudo service mysql restart`, if this doesn' work, let's investigate further :P

Comment: @hhlp, mysqld is not running in my case. Besides, `grep socket /etc/my.cnf` -> `grep: /etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @vicd, `...start...` is already in my post.

Comment: em, any thing wrong in your /var/log/mysql.log? try to post it out.

Comment: @vicd, emm.. it's empty.

Comment: how about /var/log/mysql.err

Comment: @vicd, empty as well

Comment: I just posted a potential answer, to make this more convience to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

try this command `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and check your mysql configure file is well written, I mean make sure no port conflict or spelling errors.

if you're not sure how to configure it well, just reset it to the default.

HERE IS THE DEFAULT FILE, JUST FOR REFERENCE!!!!

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP

query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M


expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]


[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: i just remove all comment in conf file to save the post space, just have a try to see if there's a configuration issue in your case.

Comment: Haven't checked my.cnf for errors, i may upload it for you. But I assume everything is fine there. The thing i miss -- `mysql.host` table.

Comment: trying to upgrade it returned -- no `mysql.host` table found. Having no idea how to restore it i've reinstalled mysql-server with no lost of existing dbs. As a result everything is working fine now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, let's assume it's fine with your configuration file, but if you have time just have a try. from the logs you provided, you may lost a table "mysql.plugin", have you upgraded your mysql? the table "mysql.plugin" seems likely be newly added in mysql 5.1. If yes, just try `mysqld --datadir=/var/data/ --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables` to ignore table checking during start progress, to if this works? I got go, let's investigate it next day. Hope you're in lucky :D

Comment: well, re-installation is like the Weapons of Mass Destruction, :P, anyway it works fine for you, but maybe it lacks some fun with investigation, :D

Comment: I was able to get it running with this command, 'mysqld --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables'. The datadir listed in the previous comment didn't exist. Now to backup my data. Thanks :-)