# MySql #2002 problem

Tags: files, apache2, mysql, database, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [My MySQL installation is broken. How to completely reconfigure it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it)

When i try to login in apache i get a `#2002` error. When i try to login in MySQL via terminal it ask my password and i get:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried to remove mysql and install it again and nothing happen ( i cant even remove it)
I try to reboot apache but still nothing.
I tried to reboot my pc and of course still aint working.

In terminal i get this:

```
$ sudo start mysql
start: Job failed to start

$ mysql -ubob -hlocalhost -P3306 -p
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

$ sudo service mysql stop
stop: Unknown instance:
```

Here is my `my.cnf` file:

```
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

I tried to find if there is a file in my `/var/run/mysqld/` or in `/var/tmp/` and dint find the file mysqld.sock... I looked in `/var/log/mysql/` and don't even have anything in it.

Can you help me? I try to find help on google for hours and din't help at all...

#### More info:

Result of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep mysql` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1335984/)

`/var/run/mysqld/` exists but it doesn't have anything in it

```
$ ls -la/var/run/mysqld/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root  40 Nov 5 22:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root  root 860 Nov   5 22:32 ..
```

my ubuntu is 12.04 LTS . can you tell me how can i make backups of my databases too?if you dont have something better then reinstall at least i can backup my databases

i tried to make backup with following:

> mysqldump -u root -p –all-databases > all_backup.sql
>
> Enter password:
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket >'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect

Comment: have you tried this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it/69450#69450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have MySQL running. Try start it using

```
 $ sudo service mysql start
```

If you still get errors check in the syslog for some info

```
$ grep mysql /var/log/syslog
```

If you can't figure the problem you can also update your answer with the log using pastebinit

```
$ grep mysql /var/log/syslog  | pastebinit
```

Also, check that `/var/run/mysqld/` directory exists and belogs to mysql user.

```
$ ls -la /var/run/mysqld
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql root   80 Nov  5 21:24 .
```

If nothing solves the problem, maybe the best way is to completely remove MySQL and install it again.

#### WARNING: this will delete all your MySQL data. So if you have important data in MySQL databases you should make a backup first!

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

#### Edit

I found this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/988801) which seems similar to yours. There's a workaround there by [Simon Hill](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/988801/comments/4) that may work with you: creating a file `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/proc` (if it dont already exists) with the following content:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#    Copyright (C) 2006 Novell/SUSE
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of version 2 of the GNU General Public
#    License published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

# @{PROC} is the location where procfs is mounted.
@{PROC}=/proc/
```

Comment: i edit it check it out

Comment: @SysteemFaillure i've updated the answer, but before you try to remove MySQL update your question with your Ubuntu version (you can get it using `cat /etc/issue`). Maybe with this someone can give you a better solution.

Comment: Salem i update my answer.if you dont have any better solution tell and i will remove mysql (but also tell me how can i make backup) and stay in touch if something goes wrong with the remove

Comment: you can't make a backup because the server can't run. To backup your data files: `sudo cp -r -p /var/lib/mysql <backup_location>`

Comment: ok my phpMyAdmin is running great again!! 3 more questions thought: How can i restore my database? is just `sudo cp -r -p <backup_location> /var/lib/mysql` ??  The file you told me to create what extansion must have? (.conf or what?) And any ideas on how i can protect my self from error 
#2002 in the future? Thanks allot mate for you help and your time! :)

Comment: i guess the only way to protect yourself is writing down the steps you made to fix it :) But if the cause was that bug i referred, then it should be fixed sometime.