# dpkg --configure -a stuck at mysql

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I was just trying to install some package through `apt-get`, then I got a message saying dpkg is broken and I need to manually run `suo dpkg --configure -a`, so I did and this is what I've got 
[image]

It is just stuck there and  won't return to command line.

I press `ctrl+c` and the program continues and outputs an error message saying :

> error processing package mysql-server-5.7(—configure): subprocess
>   installed post-installation script was interrupted

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong and is it critical?

**UPDATE**

1) I try to do `dpkg --congifure -a --force` as the error message suggests, but it says `--force` needs to take a value, so I am stuck again.

2)I try to ignore the problem and resume the installation of the package

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
```

which is in part of a PhantomJS installation. But during the process, there is also some error message regarding mysql, as shown below

[image]

After a long pause(around 3 minutes), the process continues and outputs is as below:

[image]

I will just be using PhantomJS to scrape some webpages, will these have an impact on my project in the future?

Comment: How long did you leave it hanging?

Comment: around 5 minutes before I ctrl+c

Comment: Does this help? [My MySQL installation is broken. How to completely reconfigure it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69380/my-mysql-installation-is-broken-how-to-completely-reconfigure-it)

Comment: See http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you fixed this?

Comment: this will fix a `mysql` password for `root` access?

Answer (score 0):

So, after many months with this problem, I finally solved it by doing this:

`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo mv mysql-server-5.7* ~/mysql-conf-bk-files
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-5.7`

I used the source in the comments, but the link is not available anymore, so I used archive.org to retrieve the info.